# How do I make my azure secrets read in Program.cs available to a controller?

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-keyvault, appsettings, secret-key

anyone else encountered this - you read your secrets from an azure key vault (typically in Program.cs right? Like this:

```
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
                {
                    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
                    var keyVaultEndpoint = configuration.GetSection("KeyVault").GetSection("KeyVaultEndpoint").Value);
                    var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
                    var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
                        new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
                            azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
                    builder.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultUrl, keyVaultClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());

                    var secretValue = Task.Run(async () => await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(keyVaultEndpoint, "SomeDatabasePassword")).Result.Value;
```

**How do you use this secretValue somewhere else, for example in a controller?**
Considering my appsettings looks like this:

```
{
    "KeyVault": {
               "SomeDatabasePassword": ""
     }
}
```

typically empty because we don't want to be explicitly set here in appsettings. But in Program.cs I can read that element from secrets and (while still in Program.cs)
I can overwrite the appsettings key right? Like this:
`configuration.GetSection("KeyVault").GetSection("SomeDatabasePassword").Value = secretValue;`

However if I then try to read this value `configuration.GetSection("KeyVault").GetSection("SomeDatabasePassword").Value` from a controller, I still get an empty string.

Any ideas?

Comment: After modifying the value, it is only modified in memory, you need to write/ save it back to disk before you can read it again in another part of your program. Alternatively, you could also register a service that reads, and if it isn't set, sets that value and register it for [dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59703912/how-to-let-ioptionsmonitort-get-the-latest-configuration-value-from-a-running/59744872#59744872